# What must I do to receive JSON data from a server on an android app

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have `PHP` script on the server side which executes the `SQL` query and produces a `JSON` string from it. But how do I get that code to execute to then retrieve and decode the `JSON` on the `Android` app?

I am quite new to android so as much help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an endpoint which you can hit to get the JSON?

Comment: Try using Volley to make Http requests

Comment: here is a god example you can try http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: What you want to create is called an API, search for PHP API examples, you will find a lot of those.

Comment: example you can try  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write you the whole tutorial but i can give you a to-do list which you can check your progress.

1. Your application to generate JSON script in txt, or real time response.
2. Setup your backend server(you have sql server already and also PHP, so i guess you have set it up already, probably WAMP or similar), which is the endpoint/url path to generate the response required, in this case your JSON response.
3. Check the API is working or not by using "advanced rest client" or simple type your endpoint in browser, if you can get the correct response from it, the API is working as expected.
4. Created your android app, with simple HTTP request/response, send a HTTP request to the url/path you setup, see if you can get the JSON response or not.

Please comment here if you need further details, this is relatively easy and should be able to finished in 1 day for beginner.